# Flexbox problems with iOS 6

Tags: ios, css, cross-browser, sass, flexbox

I decided to use flexbox in my project, but came across a problem. The new syntax (basing on http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

etc. seems to be working fine on FF26+ and Chrome 35+. However, Safari on iOS 6.1 is ignoring flexbox. According to a nice sandbox http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ I managed to rewrite my SASS mixins to support the older browser versions by adding vendor specific properties but it didn’t help.

For example

```
@mixin flexbox-display-row
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

The situation is messy: I can switch back to the "new syntax" ignoring the iOS 6 or I can spend hours figuring out the problem of 'old/cross syntax' to make it work on more browsers/versions.

What would be the panacea here?

Live example here: http://kleistos.lv

Comment: Can you create a *smaller* demo?  One just big enough to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @cimmanon example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6ttpLzq9/5/ . The containers should be in the center. About the problem, could say so. I guess the solution lies somewhere in vendor specific properties and values...

Comment: You do realize that demo is missing the appropriate prefixes for webkit, right?  I don't see anything centered in modern browsers, either.

Comment: Guess the problem might be this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407548/sass-mixin-with-if-else . SASS somehow skips the conditions like @if $value == 'start' OR $value == 'end' therefore generating completely glitchy output.

Comment: Anyhow, seems that my SASS mixin syntax is incorrect: lowecase or should be used instead of OR. Thank you for your help anyway ;)

Comment: Did you try -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;