# Pass a value from react component to scss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have the following code in  .jsx component,

```
<div className={type === "travellist" ? "headerContainer listmode" : "headerContainer"}>
```

In .scss how do I use the listmode for the class headerContainer?
For example:

```
.headerContainer.listmode{

            margin: 20px 0px 40px 0px;
            }
or 
    .headerContainer{

            margin: 20px 0px 100px 0px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the relationship with [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), which I recommend setting up in a build system like Webpack (e.g. with the [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) & [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) plugins). The class names can then be imported into your JavaScript. By default, each class is locally scoped (i.e. given unique names) but that can be changed with the available options.

```scss
/* In your stylesheet */
.headerContainer.listmode {
    margin: 20px 0px 40px 0px;
}
.headerContainer{
    margin: 20px 0px 100px 0px;
}
```

```js
// In JS
import { headerContainer, listmode } from './style.scss';

const className = type === 'travellist' ? `${headerContainer} ${listmode}` : `${headerContainer}`;
<div className={className}>
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but How do I export .headerContainer.listmode and .headerContainer in .scss?

Comment: Exporting of the defined class names is handled by the css-modules plugin. Here's [an example](https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo) of setting up the loader for Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article will help you.
[Can i send parameters from React to SCSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71177245/can-i-send-parameters-from-react-to-scss)

But I'm not sure why we need to send variables from React components to scss. I would appreciate it if you could let me know.